# SSRS Quarter period custom

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, parameters

I need to build a report that has custom quarter periods as shown below:

Quarter 1 - Jul, Aug, Sep
Quarter 2 - Oct, Nov, Dec
Quarter 3 - Jan, Feb, Mar
Quarter 4 - Apr, May, June

I'm a bit lost on how to approach this as I need to create a parameter where if they select quarter 1 it should only display data for the corresponding months.

Is there anyone that can suggest something?

Script looks as follows:

```
SELECT
ATD.TrnYear, 
ATD.TrnMonth, 
ATD.Invoice, 
ATD.InvoiceDate, 
ATD.Salesperson, 
ATD.Customer, 
ATD.StockCode, 
ATD.ProductClass, 
ATD.QtyInvoiced, 
ATD.NetSalesValue, 
ATD.CostValue, 
AC.Name
```

FROM
    ArTrnDetail ATD
    JOIN ArCustomer AC ON ATD.Customer = AC.Customer

So I would need to add how to distinguish when the user selects the quarter.

Much appreciated.

Comment: The answer might be quite simple but it's difficult to know without more info. Could you edit your question to supply some sample data and expected output based on one or two parameter selections.

Comment: So you have some data with a date, join this to a datedimension. Make the parameter based by quarter which you have in your datedimension. Show the values you need as labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your ATD.TrnMonth column use integer to represent months, I added an additional column to your query to indicate quarters (**QTR**). Also added the condition which will filter your result based on the user selection (**WHERE Qtr = @quarter**). This will be your dataset query.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ATD.TrnMonth IN (7,8,9) THEN 1
        WHEN ATD.TrnMonth IN (10,11,12) THEN 2
        WHEN ATD.TrnMonth IN (1,2,3) THEN 3
        WHEN ATD.TrnMonth IN (4,5,6) THEN 4
    END as Qtr,
    ATD.TrnYear, 
    ATD.TrnMonth, 
    ATD.Invoice, 
    ATD.InvoiceDate, 
    ATD.Salesperson, 
    ATD.Customer, 
    ATD.StockCode, 
    ATD.ProductClass, 
    ATD.QtyInvoiced, 
    ATD.NetSalesValue, 
    ATD.CostValue, 
    AC.Name
    FROM ArTrnDetail ATD JOIN ArCustomer AC ON ATD.Customer = AC.Customer
    ) as ArTrnDetail
WHERE Qtr = @quarter
```

In your report builder, create paramater with these settings:

GENERAL TAB

- Name: **quarter**
- Prompt: **(whatever you want displayed for user)**

AVAILABLE VALUES TAB

- select **Specify Values**, and add 4 available values.
- The **label** should be 1, 2, 3, and 4 (quarters) and the **value** should be the labels you want displayed in your dropdown list. Make sure the labels correspond with your values (quarters)

DEFAULT VALUES TAB

- For example, when the report runs and you want the report to default to the first quarter. Select **Specify Values**, put 1 in the value. Leave this tab if you don't want defaults.

Note - This is the configuration for a single value dropdown. If you want the user to be able to select multiple values. In the "General" tab of the parameter, check "Allow multiple values" and change your query condition from **WHERE Qtr = @quarter** to **WHERE Qtr IN (@quarter).**

Comment: (FLOOR((ATD.TrnMonth-1)/3)+2)%4+1 as QTR if you dont like if

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your data to a Date Dimension.

When you have done that you  would have a fact table that can be joined to your date table. Either by an surrogatekey or a businesskey.

An example could be.

**Query for Report**

```
Select SalesAmount,SalesDate,Employee from fact.Sales S
inner join Dim.Datedimension d on s.SalesDate = d.Date

where d.QuarterNo = @DateParameter
```

**Query for filter**

```
Select distinct QuarterNo,QuarterLabel(Your Quarter 1 - Jul, Aug, Sep) From Dim.Datedimension
```

QuarterNo will be your value in parameter settings.
QuarterLabel will be your label.

> Remember to adjust your date dimension to match your special quarters.